# JSON Export of Packets Dissected By Custom LUA Dissector

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I have written a custom wireshark dissector using Lua that successfully dissects packets as expected when it is installed.

When I attempt to 'Export Packet Dissections' 'As JSON', however, all of the fields handled by my custom dissector are exported as follows:

```
"_ws.lua.text": ""
```

Here is a broader snippet:

```
    "_ws.lua.fake": "",
    "my_protocol": {
      "_ws.lua.text": {
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": ""
      },
      "_ws.lua.text": {
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": "",
        "_ws.lua.text": ""
      },
      "_ws.lua.text": ""
```

What do I need to do to get the fields handled by my custom dissector to be exported properly?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? If so, would be great if you could share!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I adjusted the dissectors and thus got rid of the "_ws.lua.text"s, but not the fakes. My dissector used to look like this:

```
my_proto=Proto("my_proto", "My custom Protocol", "My custom Protocol")
*something something*
local my_proto_packet = tree:add(my_proto, buffer(),"My custom protocol");
value = buffer(curPos,4):uint();
local valueNode = my_proto_packet:add_le(buffer(curPos, 4), "value = " .. value)
```

The "value = 3.8"-String was displayed in Wireshark.

I added a `ProtoField`-variable and added it into the `proto.fields`-array. And then changed the `valueNode` definition so it now looks like this:

```
my_proto=Proto("my_proto", "My custom Protocol", "My custom Protocol")
local field_myproto_intfield = ProtoField.uint32("myproto.intfield", "Integer", base.DEC)
my_proto.fields = { field_myproto_intfield }
local my_proto_packet = tree:add(my_proto, buffer(),"My custom protocol");
*something something*

valueNode:add(field_myproto_intfield, buffer(curPos, 4))
```